# Getting StatusCode: UnsupportedMediaType when using RestClient with bearer token

Tags: c#, rest, rest-client

Getting StatusCode: UnsupportedMediaType for file upload. I am using `RestClient` with bearer token

I got the bearer token successfully, but when sending the JSON to the API I'm getting the exception unsupported media type

```
var client = new RestClient(requestAPIURL); 

var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

request.AddHeader("Authorization", string.Format("Bearer " + 
token.AccessToken));
request.AddParameter("application/json", 

JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonData), ParameterType.RequestBody);

var response = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: if you're POSTing JSON you normally add the JSON as the request body rather than a parameter

Answer (score 0):

`POST` the `JSON` in the request body:

```
request.AddBody(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonData));
```